# Gallery option for Image Selection with Description

Tags: android, listview, dialog, gallery, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to get a **menu into the gallery**, which is called by clicking a button below the images. It should look like this, but instead of these options, it should be possible to **choose the images of the gallery with a description**:

[menu http://gadgetsteria.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/gallery3.png](http://gadgetsteria.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/gallery3.png)

Additionally, in **each row** of the optionsmenu, there have to be **three entrys**: one ImageView at the left, and two TextViews on the right:

[listentry http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/images/relativelayout_wire_1.png](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/images/relativelayout_wire_1.png)

My problem is, that I don't know how I could do this on the easiest way. I've been searching the whole day and found many things that, in combination, would solve this thing, like Dialog(I would start a new Activity with the Layout of a Dialog), ListView, ListActivity, SimpleAdapter, ViewBinder, and so on..

Cause I need many different ImageGallerys, so **every Gallery has to get its own menu**, the whole thing is going to explode my mind.

And I really don't know how to combine all these pieces.

I'm thinking that there must be an easier way, maybe I overlooked something?

If not, could someone put me in the right way?

Comment: After starting the search from the beginning, I found this tutorial: http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/ . The problem is just, that the images are the same, but I have to fill each row with a different one. But I absolutely don't have an idea how to.